# How many clusters does DominantColors return?

Tags: image-processing, color, implementation-details, cluster-analysis

Is there any documentation on how it automatically chooses the number of colors - does it use X-means or some other heuristic to determine the number of clusters it automatically returns?

Comment: I should hope these type of algorithmic details - answers to which are not found in the docs - are not out of scope for this site.

Comment: `DominantColors` has to run on many different kinds of images. Black and White Images. Images over different color spaces. It's job isn't to be an algorithm. It's job is to vaguely give the kinds of results people want. We could read the code and decide to list everything that it does to different images. But even then there's no guarantee that it won't be tweaked in the next version based on some survey.

Comment: If your research requires you have a concrete algorithm for which colors are chosen, then I'd recommend writing something with `FindClusters` or the like.

Comment: ``Image`ColorOperationsDump`$DominantColorsSettings``, ``Image`ColorOperationsDump`$DominantColorsSettings2`` and ``Image`ColorOperationsDump`$DominantColorsSettingsOld`` return some stuff that may be of  interest.